# How to rename nodes in Firebase from Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase-Unity beta tool for real time data in my app. I want to change node names in the tree without override its children. For example:

```
    IFirebase firebase;
    firebase = Firebase.CreateNew ("https://test1.firebaseio.com/someChild");
    firebase_Rank.Child("ChilOne").SetValue(1);
    firebase_Rank.Child("ChilTwo").SetValue(2);
    firebase_Rank.Child("ChilThree").SetValue(3);
```

In this kind of tree is it possible to change the names of "ChildOne" without override it's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Database has no way to rename an existing node.

Most developers accomplish a rename by inserting a copy of the node with the new name and then deleting the old node.