# Efficiently move data between nodes in Firebase REST api

Tags: performance, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When using Firebase REST api, if I want to move data between node, how do I do it without having to first download the data and then re-uploading them to Firebase ?

For example, if I currently have the following data:

```
root
    branch_1
            branch_1_1
                      child
    branch_2
```

If I want to move child to branch_2, it seems the most efficient way is to download each item in child one by one, adding them to branch_2 and delete child in branch_1 afterwards.

Edit 1: change data structure to more accurately reflect needs

Comment: There is no move operation. You will have to read it from one location, add it to the second location and then remove the original.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, I'll take your answer as authoritative since you work at Firebase!

Comment: It's been answered a few times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611488/how-to-rename-parent-node, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261811/how-to-rename-nodes-in-firebase-from-unity

Answer (score 1):

Or take an entirely different approach

```
root
  branches
    -Yiujija9jsd
      branch: "branch_1"
      data: "some data"
      timestamp: "some timestamp"
    -Y88jsj9a9s
      branch: branch_2"
      data: "some other data"
      timestamp: "some timestamp"
```

then to move 'some data' from branch_1 to branch_2, just update it's branch to 'branch_2' to look like this

```
root
  branches
    -Yiujija9jsd
      branch: "branch_2"
      data: "some data"
      timestamp: "some timestamp"
    -Y88jsj9a9s
      branch: branch_2"
      data: "some other data"
      timestamp: "some timestamp"
```

*the keys are created with childByAutoId.
** I added the timestamp so it could be ordered by when it was last updated.

It's very a very flexible structure and an option to consider.

Comment: I actually wouldn't recommend this since firebase auto generated id is chronological. Thus, I'll have to somehow maintain the insertion time in the node that I'm moving too.

Comment: @QuanVuong Why? There's no mention of needing to keep a timestamp in the original question nor a mention of ordering. Can you update your initial question with the additional requirements so we understand your use case? Also since there is no move function in Firebase it enables the data to be organized in their respecting branches without having to move it - which again avoids unnecessary downloading and uploading. Just a simple set value to the branch node is all it takes.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention it in my question. I just thought it was not an optimal idea because later on, we might depend on the auto-generated id for sequencing (and another dev on the team who's not aware of the name swap might create a bug)